# Google cloudrun blocking downloading big files

Tags: google-cloud-run

I'd deployed a springboot 2.2.4 webapp on google cloudrun and I've some big files (> 100mb) served as static files inside of it. When I'm trying to access these specific files I'm getting an error 500 on log. If I try with smaller files it does work.
Does anyone knows if there are any limit related to the files size?

Thanks,
Lucas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As captured in the official [Quotas and Limits](https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas) documentation page, the maximum response size is currently 32MB